# Variable doesn’t exist in current context

Tags: c#

I've got a rather odd situation which is bound to something breathtakingly obvious, but it has me stumped.

Quite simply, I'm trying to load some configuration data into my app, as follows:

```
namespace XMLGrabberCS
{
class Grabber
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "test";
        string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
        try
        {
            //do stuff...
```

Pretty straightforward stuff, except that if you query (i.e. via Quick Watch) either variable, you get a `variable doesn’t exist in current context` error.

If you watch `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"]` it does return the right value...

What on earth is going on here?

Comment: Are you perhaps debugging a release-build?

Comment: First the obvious - are you running the debug build? Next, are the strings referenced later on in the code? If not they could be being optimised away (unlikely if you're in debug, but worth a check).

Comment: @ChrisF - you were right - for reasons I won't go into, I hadn't referenced them, but as soon as I did, there wasn't a problem. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks (and +1) to the others - sensible suggestions all-round, and worth noting for others, but not my particular problem today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the strings referenced later on in the code? If not they could be being optimised away (unlikely if you're in debug, but worth a check).

Comment: It's a silly little problem, but one that I hadn't noticed before... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Where are you when you try to use this in Quick Watch? If you're not currently debugging the `Main` method, then it's absolutely right - that variable doesn't exist.

In the Stack Trace view you can set which level of the stack you're interested in. If you double click on the stack frame with the "Main" method, it should show the variables with no problem. Unfortunately, you can't do this while the Quick Watch window is open, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Did the debugger stop in the context when you watched for the variable ?
As `ConfigurationManager` is global to the application it will work whatever the context is, so it is not surprising.